# Why can we consider only torus switch rather than arbitrary Dehn filling in Lickorish theorem?

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I understand that any orientable $3$-manifold can be obtained by doing Dehn surgery on $S^3$ along a set of circles sitting in it; but why can we further assume the slop to be $0$, i.e. we can obtain any closed orientable $3$-manifold from $3$-sphere by several torus switch?

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed explanation of Dehn surgery (and the answer of your question) [in *Dehn Surgery* by Siddhartha Gadgil.](http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~gadgil/expos/surgery.pdf)